# Navigation bar image is not loading

Tags: html, django, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add logo to my navigation bar but the image is not loading. code is as showing below,

```
<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><img src="PVPLogo.PNG" width="40" height="40" class="d-inline-block align-top"></a> 
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><h2>Electronic shop</h2></a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="true" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button> </div> </nav>
```

I added my image in the App > Images folder > PVPLogo.PNG

[image: Code Snippet]

All I can see is

[image]

Comment: Have a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

Comment: Thank you @FelixEklöf that worked.

Answer (score 0):

Your image should contain a proper address, not just the file name. For this to work you have to tell the browser, the address from where to fetch the file.

For example, if you are fetching your file from index.html you address should have been "../images/PVPLogo.PNG". The two dots tell us to go to the previous directory, then we go to the images directory and finally we fetch our image. This one is a relative path.

You can search up different kind of links and they have their advantages and disadvantages.